# Prevent Custom Actions on Patch Uninstall

Tags: wix, installation, patch

I have a product.msi having some custom action and it has been released.

patch.msp is a patch I made for product.msi.

when I remove this patch from Control panel => Add/Remove Program, custom action which in old package always run. that is not my expectation.

I don't want to run custom action when patch uninstall.

I also googled, but no good way fro released product, I can't change the wxs file to add condition for custom action.

Anyone can help me? 
Most thanks your help!

Comment: Check my updated answer. I mixed up two different posts I was answering! :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439074/windows-installer-error-1308-source-file-not-found-when-uninstalling-patch-in

Answer (score 2):

A patch features **patch-specific properties** such as **PATCH** and **MSIPATCHREMOVE**. Use these conditions on custom actions to make them run or not run during a patch depending on what is necessary.

Be careful with the conditions on custom actions, they are complicated to get right. Here is a **"[MSI Conditions Cheat Sheet](http://www.flexerasoftware.jp/webdocuments/PDF/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf)"** to help you. I have not tested these conditions - testing is the only guarantee.

I am throwing in some further **patching advice** since this is difficult stuff to deal with. Please do read to save yourself trouble. Hate sending people down the wrong track with such a problematic technology:

- If there are errors in a product's uninstall sequence your fix involves creating a very carefully designed minor upgrade that you can deliver as a patch. This is one of the best uses of a patch.
- A **minor upgrade** does not uninstall the existing installation, but rater **re-caches a new MSI file** to use for maintenance and uninstall operations. Hence you can fix the uninstall before it is run.
- Create a minor upgrade, test it fully as a regular upgrade install, and then package it as a patch. A patch is merely a distribution / delivery mechanism for an upgrade that works.
- Don't waste time making a patch before the upgrade is verified. This is a common mistake that wastes a lot of time. In fact if the minor upgrade works, a patch may not be necessary at all. Just use the minor upgrade unless your MSI file is enormously big and you want to deliver a small "hotfix".
- If you need to include files in your patch, I recommend enabling "**include whole files**". Otherwise bit-level patching is done, and this is unnecessary complexity (unless your binaries are enormous).
- Include only what you need in a patch. Add no files or settings that are not required, and you can make a reliable patch. Avoid adding custom actions if at all possible.
- Be aware that a patch uses the same InstallExecuteSequence as a regular install, but you can condition custom actions differently with patch-specific properties such as **PATCH** and **MSIPATCHREMOVE**. Use these conditions on custom actions to make them run or not run during a patch depending on what is necessary.

This "**fix uninstall approach**" is one of very few scenarios where I find MSI-patching can be successfully used. Otherwise patching is very complicated and error prone. It is also effective for small "hotfixes" to huge products - which obviously is what the whole technology is designed for.

Check Stefan Kruger's [installsite.org](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/updates.htm) for more upgrades and patching tips.

Check out [this well known wix tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization) for upgrades and patches. And [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370579.aspx).

Comment: Seems It is not What I want.

Comment: I managed to answer a different, but similar question that was on a different bulletin board! :-). I have updated the answer, see if at least part of it makes sense now.